# Angular 2 dynamic expendable nested lists

Tags: html, css, angular

I have this dynamic list created with ngFor. When I click on item I want to expand it with new dynamic list, but only for that item. In my following code it expends for every item in the first list. I understand why that is happening, but I don't have ideas how to solve it.

Here is my code

```
 <ul *ngFor="let p of portList">
    <li  (click)="setONUList(p.name)" id="{{ p.name }}"><img src="app/resources/{{ p['oper-status'] }}.png" class="myimage"/>{{ p.name}}</li>
        <ol *ngFor="let onu of portONUList">
        <li><img src="app/resources/{{ onu['oper-status'] }}.png" class="myimage" />{{ onu.name}}</li>
      </ol>

  </ul>
```

Any ideas how to solve this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, the subarray is the same which is shown for all your items, so there is no relation between the nested array and the outer array.

My suggestion would actually be to add a new property in your array, e.g `expanded`... so e.g your outer array would look like:

```
portList = [{id:1,name:'one',expanded:false},{id:2,name:"two",expanded:false}];
```

And then your HTML:

```
<ul *ngFor="let p of portList">
  <li (click)="expand(p)">{{ p.name}}</li>
  <div *ngIf="p.expanded">
    <ol *ngFor="let onu of portONUList">
      <li>{{ onu.name}}</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</ul>
```

And on click, toggle the `expanded` property:

```
expand(p: any) {
   p.expanded = !p.expanded;
}
```

Of course if you want to have a "quick" solution you could rely on HTML5 with no need of the new property:

```
<details *ngFor="let p of portList">
  <summary>{{p.name}}</summary>
    <ul *ngFor="let onu of portONUList">
      <li>{{ onu.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</details>
```

Here's a plunker with both options.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a relation between **parent** and **childlist** and the list should be in **json** format. Refer below code

```
<ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in parent" ng-click="showChilds(item)">
            <span>{{item.name}}</span>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="subItem in item.subItems" ng-show="item.active">
                    <span>{{subItem.name}}</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**Sample JSON FORMAT**

```
let parent= [
        {
            name: "Item1",
            subItems: [
                {name: "SubItem1"},
                {name: "SubItem2"}
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Item2",
            subItems: [
                {name: "SubItem3"},
                {name: "SubItem4"},
                {name: "SubItem5"}
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Item3",
            subItems: [
                {name: "SubItem6"}
            ]
        }
    ];
```